# Having issues with documenting the dynamic keyword in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: dynamic, swagger, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

We utilize Pagination, and we have a handy little class that helps us, some of it looks like this:

```
public class PagedResponse<T>
{
    public PagedResponse(HttpRequest request, IQueryable<dynamic> queryable,
           string maxPageSizeKey, dynamic options, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        //code
    }

    public dynamic Data { get; set; }
```

At some point, we execute this and assign it to Data:

```
List<dynamic> dataPage = queryable
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .ToList();
```

Because this class utilizes the dynamic type, here is what Swagger generates (imagine the type we pass to our PagedResponse class is Foo):

```
{
  "PageNumber": 0,
  "PageSize": 0,
  "MaxPageSizeAllowed": 0,
  "FirstPage": "string",
  "NextPage": "string",
  "LastPage": "string",
  "TotalPages": 0,
  "TotalRecords": 0,
  "Data": {}   <---- Here we want it to describe Foo
}
```

I also notice that when you click on 'schema' it gives it the concatenated name FooPagedResponse.

The fact that swagger doesn't give any information about Data is becoming a sticking point for our React developers who utilize some utility to grab schemas.

Now, here's the thing, if you replaced anywhere that I used dynamic with T, swagger, of course, would be happy.  But that's no solution, because **we have to use dynamic**.

Why? OdataQueryOptions and the possibility of using the odata $select command.

Before we are executing the queryable (the .ToList above), we are doing something like this (as well as other odata commands):

```
if (options.SelectExpand != null)
{
     queryable = options.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(queryable, settings) as IQueryable<dynamic>;
}
```

(options was the "dynamic options" passed to the constructor, this is the ODataQueryOptions)

Once you apply a $select you can no longer assign the `.ToList` to `List<T>` it has to be `List<dynamic>`, I get an exception otherwise about not being able to convert types.

I can't take away the ability to $select just to get proper documentation.  What can I do here?

Comment: Dynamic is an anti-pattern in OData, and just about everything, of course you can use a generic type definition but it involves a different scaffolding mechanism. What you might have been better of in doing was injecting those attributes into the standard page response rather than creating your own solution and mangement to paging.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - You mean using $skip and $top?  Also, I believe there were some advantages to applying the odata before we executed the queryable.  Especially for something like $filter.  I am really an odata noob, so if you can elaborate on your alternative ideas, but dumb it down for me, lol ... that would be cool.  If not, that's cool too.  Also, are you telling me that in my current architecture, I'm completely stuck and there is no solution?  As hours of googling has made me start to believe that.

Comment: Yes there are some issues with swashbuckle, some can be resolved, injecting additional elements into the output is tricky... If you think you need to apply the query first then that is the fundamental block you have introduced. If your logic can be made to work with `IQueryable<T>` then the OData $filter, $select, $skip and $top are all applied _directly into the SQL_... you can't get any more efficient than that.

Comment: Please post your controller logic, that is where the magic needs to happen. Using `dynamic` is two red flags my friend ;)

Comment: Look me up on codementor.io, its worth having a look at what you've done and to see what the minimal change might be to get you back on track. We use OData to make things like this easier, because we get all this OOTB

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - I put a web page up that links to two text files.  One has the full PagedResponse class, and one is an example of it's usage (which is simple).   I'm not sure if I agree on the dynamic is a red flag, because there is no option other than to use that if you want to use $select.  I was mulling all this over, and if all else fails (can't get an answer here), I'll just compile a version of the PagedResponse class using T instead of dynamic, and when they need to run their utility I will swap that in, and when they are done, swap it out to the dynamic version! lol.

Comment: OData v4 natively supports paging and already wraps the response to include meta data such as next and previous page links and total count. So $select is provided out of the box. The swagger is going wrong because you're introducing another level of nesting in the object response. The Paged response class you're suggesting is useful in Repo implementations, but OData has that support built in so you shouldn't be trying to roll out our own, to do so breaks OData compatibility

Comment: As requested before, please update your post with the controller implementation so we can provide a concrete response.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - In regards to the controller implementation, I wasn't sure what I was missing.  I added the class definition, constructor (we dependency inject some stuff), and we do extend from a "BaseApiController" that contains just some specific data to our app.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - it's 1140pm EDT, so I'm going to sign off before it becomes tomorrow in 20 minutes. lol.  Thanks so far.  I'll check tomorrow to see if I was missing anything that you need.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a direct answer to the original post, there is a lot to unpack here, too much for a simple comment.

Firstly, the original question is essentially: *How to customise the swagger documentation when returning dynamic typed responses*

- To respond to this directly would require the post to include the swagger configuration as well as an example of the implementation, not just the type.

The general mechanism for extending Swagger docs is by implementing `IDocumentFilter` or `IOpertationFilter` so have a read over these resources:

- [IOperationFilter and IDocumentFilter in ASP.NET Core](https://thecodebuzz.com/ioperationfilter-idocumentfilter-in-asp-net-core/)
- [Is there a way to get Swashbuckle to add OData parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43453743/1690217)

---

Because you are using a `dynamic` typed data response the documentation tools cannot determine the expected type so you would need to provide that information, if it is available, in another way, there are many different addons and code examples out there, but I haven't come across an implementation like this, so can't provide a specific example. Most of OData configuration is derived through reflection, so if you have obfuscated the specific implementation through `dynamic` most of the OData tools and inner workings will simply fail.

> Now, here's the thing, if you replaced anywhere that I used dynamic with T, swagger, of course, would be happy. But that's no solution, because we have to use dynamic.

The only reason that your code requires you to use a `dynamic` typed response is because it has been written in a way as to require that. This is a constraint that you have enforced on the code, it has nothing to do with EF, OData or any other constraints outside of your code. When a `$select` operation is applied to *project* a query result, we are not actually changing the *shape* of the data at all, we are simply omitting non-specified columns, in a practical sense their values will be null.

OData is very specific about this concept of projection, to simplify the processing at both the server and client ends, a `$select` (or `$expand`) query option can not modify the schema at all, it only provides a mask that is applied to the schema. It is perfectly valid to deserialise a response from a `$select` projection into the base type, however the missing fields will not be initialized.

- It is not always practical to process the projected response in the base type of the request, so many clients, especially any late-bound languages will receive the data in the same shape that it was transferred over the wire in.

---

While you *could* go deep into customising the swagger output, this post smells strongly like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), OData has a built in mechanism for paging `IQueryable<T>` responses OOTB, yes the response is different to the `PagedResponse<T>` class that you are using, it is more than adequate for typical data paging scenarios and it's implementation is very similar to your custom implementation.

*If you use the in-built paging mechanism in OData, using the `$skip` and `$top` query options, then your code implementation will be simpler and the swagger documentation would be correct.*

> You have admitted to being *new* to OData, so before blindly customising standard endpoints it is a valuable experience to first gain an understanding of the default behaviours and see if you can re-align your requirements with the standards.
>
> A key driving reason to adopt OData in the first place is to be standards compliant, so that clients can make calls against your API following standard conventions and code generation tools can create reliable client-side interfaces.   Once you start customising the in-built behaviours you must then customise the documentation or $metadata if you want to maintain compatibility with those types of processes.

By default, when a `$top` query option is provided, the response will include a link to get the next page of results. If you have not enabled the `count` to be provided automatically, you can use the `$count=true` query option to enable the overall count to be provided in the output.

The key difference between your custom implementation and the OData implementation is that the client is responsible for managing or maintaining the list of *Page Numbers* and translating them into `$top` and `$skip` values.

> This is a deliberate push from the OData team to support virtual paging or load on demand scrolling. The expectation is that the user might get to the bottom of a list and either click to see more, or by virtue of reaching the end of the current list more records would be dynamically added to the previous set, becoming a delayed load yet continuous list.

To select the 3rd page, if the page size is 5, with both a projection and a filter we could use this url:

`~/OData/Companies?$top=5&$skip=10&$select=CompanyName,TradingName&$filter=contains(CompanyName,'Bu')&$count=true`

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "~/odata/$metadata#Companies(CompanyName,TradingName)",
    "@odata.count": 12,
    "value": [
        {
            "CompanyName": "BROWERS BULBS",
            "TradingName": "Browers Bulbs"
        },
        {
            "CompanyName": "BUSHY FLOWERS",
            "TradingName": "Bushy Flowers"
        }
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "~/OData/Companies?$top=5&$skip=10&$select=CompanyName%2CTradingName&$filter=contains%28CompanyName%2C%27Bu%27%29"
}
```

This table has thousands of rows and over 30 columns, way to much to show here, so its great that I can demonstrate both `$select` and `$filter` operations.

What is interesting here is that this response represents the last page, the client code should be able to interpret this easily because the number of rows returned was less than the page count, but also because the total number of rows that match the filter criteria was 12, so 2 rows on page 3 when paging by 5 was expected.

This is still enough information on the client side to build out links to the specific individual pages but greatly reduces the processing on the server side and the repetitive content returned in the custom implementation. In other words the exact response from the custom paging implementation can easily be created from the standard response if you had a legacy need for that structure.

> Don't reinvent the wheel, just realign it.
>
> - Anthony J. D'Angelo

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but I'm having a hard-time believing there's something wrong with our solution when it works well, accepts any odata, and is fast.  There's more than one way to skin a cat.  I think the problem is swagger.  Not the code.  Imagine a DataAnnotaion for a property of a class, that told swagger that this dynamic field is really the T passed into the class.  That would solve our problem.

Comment: I can't imagine that to get around this one documentation issue, we have to rip apart our architecture, re-code everything, and have the UI developers change the way they consume everything.  That doesn't seem optimal to me.

Comment: @JustLooking it can be frustrating but that is the process we follow. At some point you have to stop hammering the square peg into the round hole. By going the 100% custom route you are introducing a level of technical debt into your API controllers, the documentation and the client side consumption. But don't fall into the trap of binding yourself so tightly to this `PagedResponse` type that you use it for other projects or even new controllers when you create them. This is a non-standard solution to something that has a very well established solution OOTB.

Comment: You can totally write the swagger docs by hand if you need to, first you'll have to post your swagger config so we can see what variant you are using, And if possible post the swagger that you want to be generated. I can put together a different answer that is more specific to just how to write the docs then.

Comment: The thing is that by doing it this way, you can't really call this _OData_ any more, especially when searching for assistance. If you already have the standard OData `IQueryable<T>` GET endpoints then you don't need to change anything on the server side at all, just leave the current endpoints there and you can gradually migrate the client side. This way you will also be designing a standard client interface that could target any OData endpoint or be easily deployed to other OData based apps.